# How do you breed a Ghost Dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

Just saw the new Ghost Dragon in the market place. What do I have to breed to get it? Best combinations?

Answer (score 2):

Cold Dragon and Earth Dragon.  You can see more information here:

[Ghost Dragon on Dragonvale Breeding Guide](http://www.dragonvalebreedingguide.com/dragon/ghost-dragon/tips-hints)

Happy breeding!

Answer (score 2):

[Adulmec's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/89468/21619) is accurate, but if you are looking for the fastest breeding pair, I would recommend either of the following:

- Cold + Mud
- Earth + Ice

I eliminated several other limited and uncommon pairings that are equivalent, since not everyone will have those.

Based on the [DragonVale Breeding Sandbox](http://www.2084.org/dragonvale/breeding-sandbox/) these pairs have a 10% chance of success with each attempt, and an average fail time of 9 hours.  When compared to a simple pairing of Cold + Earth, which has the same success chance of 10%, but a guaranteed fail rate of 14 hours, the time savings when using the above pairs is more than 2 days on average, assuming zero downtime (which is of course unrealistic).  This would be reduced if upgraded breeding cave/island is used, but would still be significant.

For those interested in the math:

### **Cold + Mud or Earth + Ice**

---

**10% Chance per attempt = 1 success / 10 attempts**

**(1 success / 10 attempts) x (1 attempt / 9 hours) = 1 success / 90 hours**

### **Cold + Earth**

---

**10% Chance per attempt = 1 success / 10 attempts**

**(1 success / 10 attempts) x (1 attempt / 14 hours) = 1 success / 140 hours**

---

### 140 - 90 = 50 hour advantage, or roughly 2 days.